# Launch an external exe and set timeout VBS

Tags: vbscript, timeout, external, launch

wanted to check with you if you can help me on that. I am using vbs to execute a specific routine and one of the steps is calling an external exe and then I want to have control if that exe takes more than X seconds and if that´s the case, kill the initial vbs and the exe itself. I´m using Wscript.Run for it and using the wait on return as true to make sure it ran.

I´ve tried using wscript.timeout but it doesnt seem to work on the external program.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [`.Terminate` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/yk84ffsf(v=vs.84)) of `WshScriptExec` object.

Comment: anyway I get able to set the timeout? Like, if the wscript takes longer than X seconds, terminate it. Thanks

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers IMO this question isn't the duplicate, since OP asks how to terminate external executable using `WScript.Timeout`, and the answers by the link don't describe that.

Comment: @omegastripes The answer provided by Matt Miller uses `WScript.Timeout`. However, setting that property does the same as starting the script with the parameter `//t`: it terminates the script. But when running an external program synchronously the script will still wait for the program to return, even if the timeout already expired. And if the program is run asynchronously only the script will be terminated after the timeout, not the external program. The cleanest way for time-limiting an external program is what I described in my answer to the other question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I just wanted to share another short and elegant solution for terminating external executable ran asynchronously via `WScript.Timeout`, that is exactly OP asks for, and wasn't posted yet.

Comment: @omegastripes Please read again. If the executable is run *asynchronously*, the timeout will **only** terminate the script itself, **not** the external program. And if the executable is run *synchronously* the timeout will basically be ignored until the external program returns. I'm not making this up.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I understand everything you pointed. And again,I share the approach where the timeout terminates both the script and external executable ran asynchronously. So please reopen the question.

Comment: @omegastripes I disagree that this question isn't a duplicate. If you have a different solution you might just as well add your own answer to the other question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for explanations.